# Adding win, lose, and tie message on a rock, paper, scissors project (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently learning how to use python and all its functions, etc. Today, I was trying to add custom messages for the player if they win, lose, or tie with the AI. I tried using if-elif-else-while but even if the player is losing, it will display the winning message at the end. It might sound easy stuff, but I don't really know how to do it after everything I tried.

I would really appreciate your help!

```py
userName = input('Tester')
userPoints = 0
aiPoints = 0
while True:
        
    userAction = input(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: {}, what is your choice? (rock, paper, scissors): ".format(userName))
    print('')
    
    while userAction != 'rock' and userAction != 'paper' and userAction != 'scissors':
        print('GAME: Ups! It looks like you inserted a word NOT valid!')
        time.sleep(1)
        userAction = input("GAME: {}TRY AGAIN! {}What is your choice? (rock, paper, scissors): ".format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT,(Style.RESET_ALL)))     

    else:  
        ai_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    ai_choice = random.choice(ai_actions)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print('')
    
    print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "                            PRE-RESULT                           ")
    print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: {} chose {} and AI chose {}.".format(userName,(userAction),(ai_choice)))
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print('')
    
    if userAction == ai_choice:
        
        userPoints = userPoints + 2  
        aiPoints = aiPoints + 2
    
        print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "         AND THE WINNER IS..UH?...Looks like we have a tie!              ")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME:",userName,"and AI chose",userAction,"which took them to a TIE game!")
        print('GAME: Both players got {}+2 points {}for tied results!'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT,(Style.RESET_ALL)))
        print('')
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You won:{} +2 Point'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI lost:{} +2 Points'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
        
        print('')
        time.sleep(1)
    elif userAction == "rock":
        if ai_choice == "scissors":
            
            userPoints = userPoints + 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints - 1
            
            print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT +"                      {} WON THIS ROUND!                           ".format(userName))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: {}'s {}{} {}was to heavy and broke AI's{} {}!".format(userName,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,userAction,Style.RESET_ALL,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,ai_choice))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You won:{} +1 Point'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI lost:{} -1 Points'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            time.sleep(1)     
            print('')
        else:
            
            userPoints = userPoints - 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints + 1
            
            print(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "                     AI AGGRESSIVELY COVERED YOU! (No, not to protect you)                 ")
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: AI's {}{} {}covered your {}{}!".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,ai_choice,Style.RESET_ALL,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,userAction))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You lost:{} -1 Point'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI won:{} +1 Points'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            
    elif userAction == "paper":
        if ai_choice == "rock":
            
            userPoints = userPoints + 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints - 1
            
            print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT +"        {} WRAPPED AI's SELECTION!                      ".format(userName))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: {}'s {}{} {}took AI's {}{} {}and wrapped it like a gift!".format(userName,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,userAction,Style.RESET_ALL,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,ai_choice,Style.RESET_ALL))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You won:{} +1 Point'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI lost:{} -1 Points'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            time.sleep(1)     
            print('')
        else:
            
            userPoints = userPoints - 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints + 1
            
            print(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "                     HOLY COW! AI JUST CUT YOUR PAPER IN HALF!                  ")
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: Yes, paper cuts are real, but AI's {}{} {}could cut a tree down like it did with {}'s {}{}!".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,ai_choice,Style.RESET_ALL,userName,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,userAction))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You lost:{} -1 Point'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI won:{} +1 Points'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            
    elif userAction == "scissors":
        if ai_choice == "paper":
            
            userPoints = userPoints + 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints - 1
            
            print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT +"        {} JUST CUT AI's RECORD!                       ".format(userName))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: What's better than cutting someone's record? Well, {}'s used {}SCISSORS {}to cut AI's{} PAPER".format(userName,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,Style.RESET_ALL,Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You won:{} +1 Point'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI lost:{} -1 Points'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            time.sleep(1)     
            print('')
        else:
            
            userPoints = userPoints - 1
            aiPoints = aiPoints + 1
            
            print(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "                 AI WENT INSANE MODE ON YOU AND BROKE YOUR SCISSORS! (No hard feelings!)           ")
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "GAME: AI was not thinking twice and broke {}'s {}!".format(userName,(userAction)))
            
            print('')
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'You lost:{} -1 Point'.format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI won:{} +1 Points'.format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + userName +"'s Total Points:{} {}".format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(userPoints)))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + 'AI Total Points:{} {}'.format(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT,(aiPoints)))
            
    play_again = input("GAME: Would you like to play another round? (y/n): ")
    print('')
    time.sleep(2)
    if play_again.lower() == "n":   

        if userPoints > 10:       
            print('')
        print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "          AND THE WINNER IS.............        ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + "                    {}!".format(userName))      
        print('')
        time.sleep(2)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: Oh Wow {}! You are actually a strong opponent!".format(userName))
        time.sleep(2)
        print("AI: But don't get too comfortable. One day, I will beat you because I am the BEST in this game (At least, that's what my programmer told me)")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("AI: Anyways, no hard feelings! I just hope you had a great time playing with me and I hope you have a wonderful day!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("AI: We'll see each other again on another game. GoodBye!") 
        time.sleep(4)
        print('')
        print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '======= FINAL SCORE ======= ')
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + "{}'s Score: {}{}".format(userName,Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT,userPoints))
        print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI's Score: {}{}".format(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT,aiPoints))
        
    
        if not userPoints > 10: #ON DEVELOPMENT
            print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "          AND THE WINNER IS.............        ")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + "                    AI!                          ")
            print('')
            time.sleep(2)
            
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: I WON! I am actually not impressed at all... I am the best player in this game!")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: I cannot lie, you did good, but not enough to beat me!")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: Hey {}, do not give up. Just keep pushing and practice and you might beat me and yes, I am challenging you!".format(userName))
            time.sleep(2)
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: It was good playing with you and I had a lot of fun, I hope you did too. No hard feelings!")
            time.sleep(2)
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI: Anyways, we will see each other again on another game. See you, {}".format(userName))          
            time.sleep(4)
            print('')
            print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '======= FINAL SCORE ======= ')
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "{}'s Score: {}{}".format(userName,Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT,userPoints))
            print(Style.RESET_ALL + "AI's Score: {}{}".format(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT,aiPoints))
            
        
    if userPoints == aiPoints:
            print("It's a TIE!")
```

Comment: For extra details, the messages I am trying to make it work are:

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the inputs/outputs of your script.

Comment: Preliminary scan of your code,  your first ```AND THE WINNER IS``` line (and subsequent lines) should belong to the ```if userPoints > 10:``` condition block

Comment: If you want help, provide code that runs.  Many things aren't defined and the indentation is wrong.  Remove all the sleeps.  Reduce the code to the smallest *working* code that reproduces the issue.  Simple "you won/lost/tied" messages to reduce the noise.  We should be able to copy it and run it without change to reproduce the described issue.

Comment: Hello, ewong and Mark. I appreciate your help on this post. Mark was right about the indentation which was crucial in my case, plus, a little logic was needed. I already had the variables for userName, it was my mistake for not adding them here. I decided to use the sleeps and long won, lost, tie, messages to make the game feel more attractive. Ewong, like I said before, inputs and outputs were not added here, it was my mistake. "AND THE WINNER IS" was set below the if user points >10: condition block. Thank you for all your help!